# mysql update records with alphanumeric 'PIN', excluding ambiguous characters

Tags: mysql

I've previously used this...

```
UPDATE whatever_table SET whatever_col = SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 12)
```

... to add a random string to a mysql table.

Now, similarly, I wish to add an alphanumeric 'PIN' to all records in a table (which will ever only be a few hundred records.) The 'PIN' should be alphanumeric but should exclude, '1', '0', 'O', 'l', etc.

Can anyone tell me how to update the query above to exclude these ambiguous characters?

TIA

Comment: Why don't you just make your database insert data and you worry about logic in the underlying language you use? Database shouldn't employ too much logic, you'll end up with more than 1 place to fish for bugs.

Comment: Yes, there's no problem inserting the 'PIN' with php when new records are being written. In this instance, however, I'm looking for a quick fix for the records that already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Besides N.B.`s comment, logic makes sense inside PL/SQL, but seriously not in (My)SQL.

> `REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str)`
>
> Returns the string str with all occurrences of the string from_str
>   replaced by the string to_str. `REPLACE()` performs a case-sensitive
>   match when searching for from_str.
>
> `mysql> SELECT REPLACE('www.mysql.com', 'w', 'Ww');`
>
> `-> 'WwWwWw.mysql.com'`
>
> This function is multi-byte safe.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 0):

for numeric:

```
select concat(2+floor(rand()*8), 2+floor(rand()*8))
```

repeat 2+floor(rand()*8) for as many digits as you need

for alphanumeric just use replace. Alternatively, you can create a table with the allowed values and cross join it on itself to create unique pins, and call those pins with a rand integer.

edit: found another nicer way  - convert rand int to base 8 (digits between 0 and 7), then add 2 to every digit making all digits between 2 and 9

> select conv(floor(rand()*10000), 10 ,8)+22222

Comment: That's great, thanks. I can live without alpha characters for the pre-existing records.

Comment: found a better way conv(floor(rand()*10000), 10 ,8)+22222